# connect to home network remotely with openvpn on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to remotely connect to my home network using a file like the client.ovpn file below.  I'm using open vpn on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.  When I run the code below:

code:

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

I get the message:

```
2023-10-25 17:04:57 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
2023-10-25 17:04:57 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-128-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-128-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-128-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-128-CBC' to silence this warning.
2023-10-25 17:04:57 OpenVPN 2.5.5 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 14 2022
2023-10-25 17:04:57 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
```

when I enter the username and password below:

```
Enter Auth Username: examplename
 Enter Auth Password: ********  
password:
```

I get the message:

```
2023-10-25 17:05:19 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
2023-10-25 17:05:19 OpenSSL: error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak
2023-10-25 17:05:19 Cannot load inline certificate file
2023-10-25 17:05:19 Exiting due to fatal error
```

example client.ovpn below:

```
remote xxx.xxx.x.xx xxx
float
nobind
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
keepalive 15 60
comp-lzo adaptive
auth-user-pass
client
auth SHA1
cipher AES-128-CBC
remote-cert-tls server
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxx=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

</ca>

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxx=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

</key>
```

can you see what the issue might be and can you suggest what I can do to get the vpn to work with openvpn so I can connect to my home network on vpn with my ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but in your client.ovpn file you have `remote-cert-tl server`. I think there is a typo and should be `remote-cert-tls server`

Comment: @mpboden thanks for pointing that out, yeah I caught it a little while ago and updated but I'm still getting the same error message.  I'll update the type-o in the post.